# How do I display "News" on the Home page? (Magento)

Tags: magento

I need news articles to be displayed on the front page but the standard way, to put this code `{{block type="profile/profile" name="profile" template="profile/news-front.phtml"}}` in the editor on backend doesn't work, even though I have created file `news-front.phtml` in the `template/profile`. I really-really need help with this. The output in `system.log` is `Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/profile/news-front.phtml`

Comment: Is ~profile/news-front.phtml~ present in the theme that is active?

Comment: This isn't "the" standard way. There are multiple ways, none more "standard" than the other. Not being snarky, just wanted to put that out there. Also, this is not a core Magento block. What module are you using? The vendor should help.

Comment: @benmarks: then would you care to share other ways of displaying news on the home page?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to whether you want the news block to be displayed within the content area or as a left or right hand block

Comment: @JonDay: oh, sorry forgot, `content` area

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer - There's your current approach (including a block via CMS directives), including a block via Layout XML in CMS, including a block via Layout XML from filesystem, or using a new route (not using the CMS system at all).

Comment: @benmarks: I would like to stick with current approach

Answer (score 0):

Is the block type really going to be profile/profile? If you are just hoping to output the file as PHP/HTML you may want to consider using core/template rather than profile/profile.

Comment: I will add that I have found many times that if the block does not exist in Magento, it will not display anything. This is usually the first thing I check.

Comment: Actually I just looked at a layout file and I think I actually meant core/template.

Comment: @JoshPennington: profile/profile exists, and this example I found on the Magento forum, people were giving feedback that it works :S

Comment: It may exist on their installation, but does it exist in your installation. I do not see anything related to profile in the installation I am looking at.